# Reason of fork problems unclear

Tags: process, forking

I have a Debian based Linux system. After some updates (not related to Debian core repos) the system had some leaking leading to forking problems after a couple of days for new spawned processes like this:

```
/usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: 152: /usr/share/sendmail/sendmail: Cannot fork
```

The problem is I did not find any message in the system logs neither journalctl nor syslog nor dmesg about the reason of the failed fork. As related to sendmail I got this at least in its log:

```
sm-mta[12135]: 3AK902ah012135: SYSERR(root): doworklist: cannot fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

So how to see and identify these failed forks from a system point of view?